# Talend OS - activating Log4j in components prints to STDOUT

Tags: log4j, talend

We have an expected unique-constraint error condition in a tJDBCOutput component that we want to ignore.  We run our exported job via a cron that sends emails for anything sent to the console/STDOUT.

That was working fine originally with the default logging configuration --
[old/default log4j config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77T0j.png)

But after changing it to enable Log4j in components, we're now getting emails from our cron jobs on these conditions.  By the looks of the configuration, WARN messages should be going to the file, not the file and STDOUT.
[activated log4j config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO7fh.png)

How can we just log this and now see the STDOUT lines?

Tried changing the root level but that gets rid of the logged WARN level information we do want.